# Multiple sub-figures arranged on one page

Tags: floats, subfloats, minipage

I would like to arrange 4 sets of 3 subfigures onto one page as shown in the attached picture. I want each of the 4 sets of subfigures to have their own figure number and caption. Is it possible to split the page into quarters in which I could place the subfigure?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always show a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you already have and use this MWE to explain your problem.

Comment: You should not add comments to answers into your question. Ask a follow-up question with MWE (see link above) if you have a problem adapting answers for your own problem. See, e.g., https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7453 for problems with editing answered questions.

Answer (score 2):

Into one `figure` environment arrange as many `subfloat` (`subfig` package) and `caption` you need. Following code uses `minipages` to distribute the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[][first]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][second]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][third]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}
\caption{First row, first column}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
\subfloat[][first]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][second]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][third]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}
\caption{First row, second column}
\end{minipage}\\[2cm]
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
\subfloat[][first]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][second]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][third]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}
\caption{Second row, first column}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}\centering
\subfloat[][first]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][second]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
\subfloat[][third]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image}}
\caption{Second row, second column}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine several `minipage` environments with, e.g., `\subcaptionbox` inside one `figure`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example-image

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \subcaptionbox{First
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{Second subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \subcaptionbox{Third
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the first figure}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \subcaptionbox{First
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{Second subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \subcaptionbox{Third
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the second figure}
  \end{minipage}

  \bigskip
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \subcaptionbox{First
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{Second subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \subcaptionbox{Third
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the third figure}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \subcaptionbox{First
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{Second subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
    \subcaptionbox{Third
      subfigure}[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[height=2em,width=.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the forth figure}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: own number]

Note: `floatrow` allows only one `\caption` per float unless you use, e.g., `\ffigbox`. See the `floatrow` manual, section 1.2 for more information.

Comment: i observe that you liked `\subcaptionbox` environment :-). +1 for nice answer.

Comment: @Zarko: Maybe I like `\subcaptionbox` *command*. But mostly I like to use a package with very good support of a very pleasing author.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative with using `tabularx` and `subfig` packages ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% for example-image
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                        *{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
                               @{} }
    \subfloat[First subfigure] {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the first figure}
        &
    \subfloat[First subfigure] {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the second figure}
        \\
%
    \subfloat[First subfigure] {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the third figure}
        &
    \subfloat[First subfigure] {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

    \subfloat[First subfigure]     {\includegraphics[height=4em,width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
    \caption{This is the forth figure}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]